# Simple python function returning None, AND I am using a return statement

Tags: python

I have no idea why this is returning None

```
def list_union(self,A,B):
    A = self.separate(A["fill"])
    B = self.separate(B["fill"])
    print A
    print B
    if len(A)==1 and A[0]=="no":
        return B.sort()
    if len(B)==1 and B[0]=="no":
        return ["no"]
```

Just assume and A and B are being returned as a list type( which it is and it is working fine)

A and B may contain the strings yes or no. I just don't get why they are returning None.

Let me add, I don't care if these two are statements are false because there is more to this program, but I figure whatever issue I am having can be solved by figuring out why this isn't working.

Comment: What if neither condition evaluates to `True`?

Comment: `B.sort()` returns `None`. Use `sorted(B)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`B.sort()` doesn't return B, it returns `None` !
(But B is sorted as you wanted)

You can use `sorted(B)` that will return what you want.

Indeed, the built-in sort() method modifies the list in-place.

sorted() built-in function builds a new sorted list.

Comment: I like this answer because it actually answered my question and didn't bother with extra details. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

By default a function in Python returns `None`. In your case, it has two exit points, but they will be reached *only* if one of the conditions is `True`. Ask yourself, what happens if both conditions are `False`? add another return at the end, to handle this case and return an appropriate value (or raise an exception, if it makes sense):

```
return "Unexpected result" # just an example
```

Also, notice that `sort()` does *not* return a value (it sorts the list in-place), so it'll evaluate to `None`, too! In other words, you should change this line:

```
return B.sort()
```

Do this instead:

```
B.sort()
return B
```

Or do this, which *does* return a new sorted list:

```
return sorted(B)
```